# Add custom header to Material Ui Multiselect

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've been struggling with finding out how to add a search bar to a multi select that only shows once you click on the multiselect and the popover shows up. The Problem if you add it as a MenuItem it is selectable but it's not supposed to be an option. So is there a way to add the custom header in the popover Paper but not inside the UL for the Menuitems?

What I tried so far was:

```
<Select {props...}>
    <MenuItem><input value={value} id="search" /></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>2</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Comment: Hi have you looked at? [material-ui-autocomplete-multiple](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#Tags.js)

Comment: @SakisTsalk yes but sadly its not of help because I need the select and the search is inside the popover.